# Word documents that are configured as landscape mode are printed as portrait and vice versa

Tags: printing

I work as a SysAdmin in a organization and I have this super weird problem, whenever I try to print a word document that is configured as portrait mode it prints in landscape and vice versa.

The problem occur only when with a specific user on the computer. If I login with my account then it prints normally.

I thought about there is some problem with the user, but I am not sure about it.

Hope someone know how to fix this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please remember that Printer Preferences and Printer Properties, are profile based, regardless if it's a shared printer nor locally installed. Kindly check the Printing Preferences of the printer and check it's "Orientation", most of the time, you can see it there if you are using the latest PCL driver for the printer. Hope this helps!